# Using a navigation bar to get something similar to the picker in the iPhone Safari app?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationbar, uipickerview

In Safari, when I press a dropdown box, a picker comes up with a navigation bar on top of it that has a done button and some other buttons.

I want a similar bar with two buttons above my picker view, but I can't figure out how to put buttons on the bar. With a navigation controller, I'd do:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [UIButton .....
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [UIButton ......
```

But I'm not finding any button properties on the navigation bar that I'm creating programmatically. Adding the buttons as subviews also doesn't seem to be doing anything. How can I add them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s a toolbar, not a navigation bar. Set its `items` property to populate it with UIBarButtonItem objects. Note that those are not the same as UIButtons, and in fact don’t even subclass from UIView; they have their own set of attributes. A simple example:

```
UIToolbar *toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
toolbar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                    [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil] autorelease],
                    [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(doneButtonPressed)] autorelease],
                    nil];
someTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolbar;
[toolbar release];
```